# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 time of day data type

Tags: sql-server

Is there a data type which represents time of day?  Such as a datetime data type without the date.

when i format 41 seconds into a datetime data type this is what I get:

```
1/1/1900 12:00:41 AM
```

I'm trying to store a duration of time in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, there is a `Time` data type which only stores the time. In versions of SQL Server prior to 2008, your only choice is the `DateTime` data type (and `SmallDateTime`) which stores both the date and the time. However, there are means in most languages including T-SQL to show the time portion. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Thomas I'm trying to store a duration of time in a table.  Then sum several rows together using a group by statement.  Perhaps what I could do is store #of ms from midnight

Answer (score 0):

Not in 2005 no, there are plenty of discussions around on this subject.

[This being just one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812631/store-time-of-the-day-in-sql)